# Cobertura, Findbugs and Checkstyle in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube-5.0

I've installed Sonarqube-5.1 on my local machine and i am a new bee to it. I 've installed Cobertura, Checkstyle and Findbugs plugin on my local instance of SonarQube. However, I am not able to configure these plugins in sonarqube.

My understanding is that, after these plugins are configured in sonar. I will do mvn sonar:sonar which will utilise these plugins, push the data in database and i can directly see these reports on sonar dashboard.

Help reqd
1. How to configure these plugins in sonar after installtion is done?
2. Do we need add specific widgets for these plugin to see their reports on the dashboard?